# Android 13 (SDK 33) does not show permission dialog?

Tags: android, storage, android-permissions, media

I want to show the permission dialog when clicking a button. It works below Android SDK 33 with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but SDK 33 does not show with READ_MEDIA_VIDEO (Min SDK 21 Max 33)

```
  binding.imageView10.setOnClickListener {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@VideosActivity, " Permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
                }
            } else {
                videoPickDialog()
            }

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        READ_MEDIA_VIDEO)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@VideosActivity, " Permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        arrayOf(READ_MEDIA_VIDEO),
                        GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
                }
            } else {
                videoPickDialog()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to request that READ and WRITE permission for external storage on an Android 13 device. They do not work anymore then.

Comment: Instead you can use the three MEDIA_READ_.... permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the condition of the first if with:

```
(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
```

TIRAMISU is higher than M thats why it will also go into the first block for api 33 devices.

**OR**

Change the order of the two if statements:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        READ_MEDIA_VIDEO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this@VideosActivity, " Permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        } else {
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                   arrayOf(READ_MEDIA_VIDEO),
                   GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    } else {
        videoPickDialog()
    }
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                  android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
              Toast.makeText(this@VideosActivity, " Permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    } else {
                videoPickDialog()
}
```